# How to use Mongo Bulk together with multi-document transactions in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, bulkinsert

I want to run a bulk operation in mongo but at the same time run it inside a multi document transaction. I am using Meteor running the NodeJs driver of MongoDb.

According to the MongoDB documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) it should be possible to combine `Bulk` and `multi-document transactions`. However, I have not been able to solve this.

My problem is how to pass the `session` object to the Bulk operations. For non-bulk operations we just pass it as an options object `const options = {session: session}`. I have tried to pass it in several ways but nothing seems to work.

How should the `session` object be used in `Bulk` operations?

Below is a simple example of what I am trying to achive.

```
const getMongoClient = function() {
  const { client } = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo;
  return client;
}


const session = client.startSession();
try {
  session.startTransaction();
  const bulk = someCollectionToBulkWrite.rawCollection().initializeOrderedBulkOp(); // Pass the session here?

  const dataInsert = someCollection.insert(someObject, {session}).await().value;
  const dataInsertOtherDocument = someOtherCollection.insert(someOtherObject, {session}).await().value;

  bulk.find( { _id: someId } ).update( { $set: { testField: 3}}); //Or pass the session here?
  bulk.find( { _id: someOtherId } ).update( { $set: { testField: 3}});

  bulk.execute().await(); // Or pass the session here?

  session.commitTransaction().await();
} finally {
  session.endSession();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the code for the MongoDB driver for NodeJS and more specifically for the `Bulk` API (https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/bulk/common.js)

The definition of the `execute` methods looks as follows:

`execute(_writeConcern, options, callback);`

The session should thus be passed as the second argument to `execute`. In the example provided in the question that would look like this:

`bulk.execute(null, {session}).await();`

Comment: link is not available @Euklides

Comment: Now at least with `mongodb` driver `v4.1.4` the call would be `bulk.execute({ session })`.